# Getting "The jboss EAP 6.0.1 service on local computer started and then stopped" error on JBoss server startup

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I am using JBoss EAP 6.0.1, which I've configured to run as a service on a windows based machine using JBoss provided native client.

I configured my Java app and it has been running for the past year without any issues; for the past 2 days on reboot the JBoss EAP 6.0l service is no longer starting and I'm getting the below error when starting the service manually:

**"The JBoss Application Server 6.0.1 service on local computer started and then stopped. Some service stops automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs"**

There was no cinfugchanges or windows updates on my machine; please let me know how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: what about jboss logs and event log?

Comment: Nothing related to start-up failure is logged to JBoss server logs and no ERROR  events found on Event log

Comment: this question lacks the details to debug the issue. You could start with providing full details how exactly is your service configured, does it start with directly invoking, can you connect to the server using a debugger...